# List of Countries using NSLocaleCountryCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nslocale

I want to be able to make the app change depending on the users location. Im using the code below:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
    NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
    NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
    NSLog(@"countryName %@", countryName);
```

which works great, but I want to know how the `countryName`'s will be displayed, so I can set up switch case's, which is hard if you dont know how exactly each country is spelt: USA, United States, United States of America, etc. Is there a list of countryCode from Apple, I cant find one.

Also is there a way to make sure the result is in English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple uses the [ISO-3166 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).

Comment: -1: Link-only answers are poor answers because the link can be broken (as this currently is). You should include the relevant information *within your answer* and a link to the original page/info as an additional resource or attribution.

Comment: In Great Britain [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode]; returns 'GB' which is not in the ISO-3166 list (it's not a country!)

Comment: In Swift, NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes()

Answer (score 7):

"ISO standard ISO-3166" is accurate in most cases, but try selecting "Europe" as a region in iOS settings. You will get a return value of "150". Why "150"? Seems like a region code from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_M.49. Or from here: http://site.icu-project.org/design/t/territory-region-apis

Answer (score 2):

[`NSLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html) gets its data from [`CFLocale`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF) which in turn gets its data from the 
[ICU - International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org) (Apple keep copies [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/)). The file `/icuSources/common/uloc.cpp` contains almost all the information we usually see returned.

However, `/cldrFiles/supplementalData.xml` may be the primary source. This file comes from the [CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/index).